# Eclipse debugger stops the program in non-breakpoint line of it

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to debug a program written in Java. I used breakpoints to solve my program issues and I solved some of them and removed the breakpoints after that. Now every time I run the debugger it stops the program in a place that used to be a breakpoint (not any more), and because I have iterative program it takes me so much time to pass these let's say invisible breakpoints in debugger and reach the real breakpoints. I tried to put breakpoints and removed then,nothing changed. It happens only for some of removed breakpoints not all of them. 
Any idea would be appreciated.

I am using :
Eclipse Version: 4.2.2
Build id: M20130204-1200
Java vesrion: 1.7.0_40-b43

Update:
**Run->Remove All Breakpoints** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your java classes and war/ear/jar are in sync. To be on the safe side, delete the war/ear/jar, rebuild & deploy, this should resolve your issue